# Any way to overlay an image over a slick slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im attempting to recreate the sliding effect as seen on here: [www.sugarcrm.com](http://www.sugarcrm.com).

I just need the sliding part and not the beginning animation. I tried using a slick slider because its responsive, however in order to overlay the PNG image over it I would need to make the position absolute as well as a z-index.  But as soon as I do that everything goes out of wack.  Is there a way to achieve this effect while still maintaining responsiveness? With or without slick plugin. Thank you all!

```
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #container {
        width: 1920px;
        height: 455px;
        background: transparent;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .your-class {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick-1.4.1/slick-1.4.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.your-class').slick({
        autoplay:true,
        arrows: false,
        draggable: false,
        mobileFirst: true,
        pauseOnHover: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="your-class">

        <div>
            <img class="images" src="img1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="images" src="img2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="images" src="img3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="images" src="img4.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

Comment: could you please include some code?

Comment: Can you include the relevant source code with your attempt of doing this please. People will debug your code and explain why everything goes out of wack and give you solutions if they have any. If not then you might find people will down vote this question due to no resources to work with and no attempt of your own is being displayed.

Comment: do you need the text and the image to slide in?  or just the image behind the overlay?

Comment: both the image and text. preferably in two seperate entities. I can replicate the effect using basic z-index however I need it to be responsive which is why im using slick. any suggestions?